# Elasticsearch not refresh ram memory

Tags: memory, elasticsearch

I use ES for index of notifications, notifications are changing daily and number is around 120 000 daily.

Since there are frequent changes (delete old and add new) I've noticed that the memory is increased by 1GB per day. However, when I restart the ES server memory is reduced to about 1GB. Not a solution to restart the server once a day.

It seems to me that the deleted documents remain in RAM memory.

I have one server with 95GB RAM.

```
ES version : {
    "number" : "0.90.1",
    "snapshot_build" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.3"
  },
```

ES settings are default.

Is there a way to remove deleted documents from ram memory?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you measuring RAM usage? Note that ES runs on the JVM so a fair amount has to do with the JVM settings you are running with, plus as much of the rest of memory as it can get will be used for filesystem cache. Are you running anything else on this server?

Comment: Yes, I running a memcached and node.js. I use new relic for analize. Here is http://postimg.org/image/ur13diner/ screenshot from newrelic panel. You mean that JVM use ram, not elasticsearch?